# EF4: Splitting a table to two entities using POCOs - why am I getting an exception?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4, lazy-loading, poco

I have one table **"Courses"** mapped to two entities **"Course"** and **"CourseDetails"**.
Both have **POCO** classes with **virtual** navigation properties.
Both entities use same ID (Identity on Course but not on CourseDetail).
Mapping between entities is a "**referential integrity constraint**" not in "mappings" window.
Course is principle in constraint.

I am using **LazingLoading** and **ProxyCreationEnabled**.

After calling **context.SaveChanges()** the connects look fine (IDs, references and data).

When accessing course.CourseDetails from within a loop on context.Courses I get the default empty CourseDetails created by Course's constructor instead of the actual CourseDetails data!?

When I call **context.LoadProperty(course, c => c.CourseDetails)** I get an **InvalidOperationException** with the message:

"***Multiplicity constraint violated. The role 'CourseDetails' of the relationship 'OrmComparisons.EFPocos1.CourseDetailsCourse' has multiplicity 1 or 0..1.***"

Question 1: Why is course.CourseDetails empty?
Question 2: Why am I receiving an exception?
Question 3: What should I be doing instead?

I can share the solution + sql file if anyone wants to look.

Comment: :- I am facing same issue. I am using ADO.Net POCO entity generator for generating classes. I am pulling my hair and not able to fix it. I got exact scenario as yours and I am not using Hand written POCO classes too.

Comment: Can you submit a new question with you tables, entities, mappings and the test code that fails? Post a link to the question as a comment here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After comparing self written POCOs with template generated POCOs,
I noticed the Fix___ methods, which are meant to fix navigation properties.
Some how all other types of relationships (one to many, many to many, inheritance)
work with virtual properties and lazy loading.
Only the table splitting to one-to-one relationship.

Anyway - fix was using t4 generated POCOs and not self written POCOs with simple { get; set; } properties.